# Creating new task for logged in user: Django rest framework

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

In my project, the user who is logged-in can create new tasks and access their connect. All the content that was created by the logged-in user can retrieve their's stuff. I also created a custom user model for this project which I already declare in my settings.py `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'user.CustomUser'`.
I'm using djangorestframework-simplejwt for authentication. However, for some reason whenever I try to create a new task, it throws an error `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "author_id" of relation "app_task" violates not-null constraint`
I've been trying to find solutions but nothing worked at this moment. Is there any way django can know who is currently logged-in and retrieve the user's information?

User model

```
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_('User must have an email'))
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        if password == '':
            raise ValueError(_('Password can not be empty'))
        if password is None:
            raise ValueError(_('Password can not be Null value'))
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):

        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_("Superuser must be is_staff=True."))
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_("Superuser must be is_superuser=True."))
        if extra_fields.get('is_active') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_("Superuser must be is_active=True."))

        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)


class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

Task view

```
class TaskListCreateView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = TaskSerializer
    queryset = Task.objects.all()
```

Task serializer

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ('id', 'task_name', 'comments', 'status')
```

Task model

```
class Task(models.Model):
    class TaskObjects(models.Manager):
        def get_queryset(self):
            return super().get_queryset().filter(status='active')

    options = (
        ('active', 'active'),
        ('completed', 'completed'),
    )

    task_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    comments = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, default='')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=options, default='active')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='app_tasks')
    objects = models.Manager()  # default manager
    taskobjects = TaskObjects()  # custom manager

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created_at',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.task_name
```

I also modify the TokenObtainPairView and TokenObtainPairSerializer

```
class CustomTokenObtainPairView(TokenViewBase):


    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = CustomTokenPairSerializer(data=request.data)
        try:
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        except AuthenticationFailed:
            raise InActiveUser()

        return Response(serializer.validated_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

```
class InActiveUser(AuthenticationFailed):
    status_code = status.HTTP_406_NOT_ACCEPTABLE
    default_detail = "User is not active, please activate your account"
    default_code = 'user_is_inactive'


class CustomTokenPairSerializer(TokenObtainSerializer):
    @classmethod
    def get_token(cls, user):
        return RefreshToken.for_user(user)

    def validate(self, attrs):
        data = super().validate(attrs)
        if not self.user.is_active:
            raise InActiveUser()

        refresh = self.get_token(self.user)

        data['refresh'] = str(refresh)
        data['access'] = str(refresh.access_token)

        return data
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: the error is self explanatory, you need to create Task object with author field not null. Or make that field null.

Comment: @SandeepBalagopal wouldn't that make the "task" without author? I want the author field of the Task object to be the currently logged-in user.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.
If there are other solutions, please let me know.

By overriding perfom_create(), it allows me to save a new task with the currently logged-in user as author.

```
class TaskListCreateView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = TaskSerializer
    
 
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(author=self.request.user)
     
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Task.objects.filter(author=self.request.user)
```